# Designators, quantifications and predicates in Predicate Logic

Tags: logic, homework

So, I got my Predicate Logic exercises back, and I had apprently made one mistake. What is annoying is that I don't know why.

The taks was to identify all the designators and predicates in a certain number of sentences. The one I got wrong on was this:

> "Everyone tells the officer to keep an eye on City Hall"

I identified two designators here, and three predicates, like this:

> Designators:
>
> > ```
> >  the officer  
> >  City hall
> > ```
>
> Predicates:
>
> > ```
> >  Everyone tells x to keep an eye on City hall 
> >  Everyone tells the officer to keep an eye on y 
> >  Everyone tells x to keep an eye on y
> > ```

Where I had gone wrong was apparently in the last predicate ("everyone tells x to keep an eye on y"), for there my teacher had crossed out "Everyone" and put "z", like this

> > ```
> >  z tells x to keep an eye on y
> > ```

My questions are:

> > 1) Why is everyone substituted for z, when I have explicitly learned that "everyone, each, some, all, none, etc are **not** designators", and I though one could only remove designators to make predicates ...
> >
> > 2) Why is it only substituted for z in the last predicate and not in the two first one?
> >
> > 3) Why is it "everone" not listed as a designator, when it is removed for the sentence?

Thanks!

Comment: Only your teacher knows the answer to that question and you will have to get it by asking them. Certainly no one here can tell you. "Designator" is not a common term in [Predicate Calculus](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/logicguide.pdf); it appears to mean neither "Quantifier" nor "Argument", which are the standard terms.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about formal logic.

Answer (score 1):

**Designators** come in different varieties: as proper names like ‘Barack Obama’ or ‘the Eiffel Tower’ or as definite descriptions like ‘the tallest student in Oxford’; and there are more. Designators (purport to) refer to one single object.

The pronoun *Everyone* is also a **designator** in the example sentence.

*Everyone* tells *the officer* to keep an eye on *City Hall*
-----z---- ..P2.. ----x------ .............P1........... ----y-----

Comment: You may like to ask this question on [linguistics.se] or on a logic site. It's less about the English language *per se*.